# Need to split large csv file

Tags: text-processing

I've got this csv file that needs to be broken up in smaller files.
no problem with split -l 20000 test.csv my problem is that the file contains different headers. want to split say every +-1000 lines but it needs to split after pay header and new file needs to start with cust header.

```
cust header,xxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx
txn header,xxxx,xxx,,xxxx,xxxxx,,xxx
detail header,xxxx,xxxx,xxxxxx,xxxx,xxxx
detail header,xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxx,,
pay header,,,,,xxxx,xxxxx
cust header,xxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx
txn header,xxxx,xxx,,xxxx,xxxxx,,xxx
detail header,xxxx,xxxx,xxxxxx,xxxx,xxxx
pay header,,,,,xxxx,xxxxx
cust header,xxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx
txn header,xxxx,xxx,,xxxx,xxxxx,,xxx
detail header,xxxx,xxxx,xxxxxx,xxxx,xxxx
pay header,,,,,xxxx,xxxxx
```

Comment: what should the output files look like? I assume it's not just one set of headers per file.

Comment: Will the cust header sections need to be broken into multiple files with cust header at top of each file, e.g. cust header1 - lines 1-1000 and cust header1 -line 1001-1999; cust header2 -  lines 1-200; cust header3 - lines 1-1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ilkkachu's solution is slick, uses a single executable, and is <strike>probably</strike> the correct answer.  However, I've just never been able to wrap my head around advanced uses of `awk`.  Had ilkkachu not answered first, I might have opted for `csplit`.  `csplit` will split a text file based on *context lines* (okay, regular expressions).  You could then take that output and further split the files with the `split` utility you already know:

```
$ csplit --prefix="MySplit." test.csv '/^cust header,/' '{*}'
0
174
134
134
```

Those are the byte counts of each chunk (which we ignore in this case).  Now, iterate over each `MySplit` chunk and further split to your 20k requirement:

```
$ for i in MySplit.0*; do
    split --additional-suffix=".$i" -l 20000 "$i"
  done
```

For example, using `-l 2` instead of 20k, the final output given your sample would be (sorted by extension):

```
$ ls -lhXB
total 44K
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke   0 Jun 15 13:31 MySplit.00
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke 174 Jun 15 13:31 MySplit.01
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke  67 Jun 15 13:27 xaa.MySplit.01
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke  81 Jun 15 13:27 xab.MySplit.01
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke  26 Jun 15 13:27 xac.MySplit.01
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke 134 Jun 15 13:31 MySplit.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke  67 Jun 15 13:27 xaa.MySplit.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke  67 Jun 15 13:27 xab.MySplit.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke 134 Jun 15 13:31 MySplit.03
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke  67 Jun 15 13:27 xaa.MySplit.03
-rw-r--r-- 1 hunteke hunteke  67 Jun 15 13:27 xab.MySplit.03
-rw-r--r-- 2 hunteke hunteke 442 Jun 15 13:06 test.csv
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this with `awk`:

```
awk -vfilename=output -vcut=1000  '
    BEGIN { nl=0; nf=1; f=filename "." nf;} 
    ++nl >= cut && /^cust header,/ {
         close(f); nl=0; f=filename "." ++nf}
   {print > f}' < file
```

It keeps a count of the lines it's seen, and reopens a new output file if the count is larger than `cut` (1000 here), and the current line starts with `cust header,`. The output files are named `output.1`, `output.2`, ... (the `filename` variable)